# Issue of StretchDIBits to firebreath windowless window in IE10 on win8

Tags: windows-8, activex, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10, firebreath

I use Firebreath to create a cross browser plugin to do 3D graphics rendering.

The actual drawing happens in my native code on an offscreen target, and each time flush will call myplugin::onWindowRefresh, which will StretchBlt to the windowless window of plugin, code like below,

```
FB::PluginWindowlessWin *win = dynamic_cast<FB::PluginWindowlessWin*>(pluginWindow);
dstHdc = win->getHDC();
if(srcDib && dstHdc)
{
  FB::Rect r = win->getWindowPosition();
  int dstWidth = r.right - r.left; 
  int dstHeight = r.bottom - r.top;

  SetStretchBltMode(dstHdc, HALFTONE);
  StretchDIBits(dstHdc, r.left, r.top, dstWidth, dstHeight, 0, 0, srcWidth, srcHeight,
  srcDib->GetBits(), srcDib->GetBitmapInfo(), DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY);
}
```

Everything works well until I try my plugin on win8 in IE10. The issue is

The window position got from windowless window is not **window position** any more, it behaves like **plugin position**, which means the destination HDC of windowless plugin is in plugin-space coordinates, but in other case (IE9, chrome, firefox, etc), it is window-space coordinates.

So, is it a problem with IE10 on win8 or firebreath issue?
Any help/suggestions are appreciated.

**Update:**
The issue only happens in IE10 on win8. I just installed IE10 on win7, and My plugin works well.

Comment: I am having the issue as well, just FYI; it's entirely possible FireBreath is doing something wrong, but unfortunately I don't know what it is.  This is on my list of things to fix eventually but we just don't have enough clients using our plugins on win8 for me to have taken time to figure out what is going on.  It's more an activex issue than specifically firebreath, though

Comment: This issue also affects IE11 on both WIndows 8 and Window 10. IE 11 Windows 7 is unaffected by this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the fix for this is to use the bounds in the RefreshEvent instead of getWindowPosition.

```
FB::Rect r = dynamic_cast<FB::RefreshEvent*>(evt)->bounds;
```

That will probably fix your issue.

Comment: Great stuff. This appears to have solved a similar issue for me.